# How do I create a:hover effect on menuitems?

Tags: css, primefaces, hover, xhtml

I am doing a wesite and I want to add hover effect for each menu items.I used Primefaces for menubar.For example, I hover over the mainpage, background color of mainpage should become red; I hover over the about, background color of about should become blue etc. How can I do?

```
<p:breadCrumb>
    <p:menuitem value="Main Page" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="About" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="Team" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="Gallery" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="Contact" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />
</p:breadCrumb>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not familiar with how primefaces works, but I know you can use attribute selectors in css:

```
[value="Main Page"]:hover {
  background-color: red;
} 
[value="About"]:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
// ...etc.
```

Here's some information about css attribute selectors and how they work: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

**UPDATE**
Since attribute selectors didn't work, how about this:

```
<p:menuitem styleClass="main" value="Main Page" style="text-decoration: none" url="#" />   

.main:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Sara: How can an answer that did not work geaccepted. If it worked after the edit, please remove your comment above. It is misleading

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        form
        {
            height:600px;
            width:600px;
            border:2px solid red;
        }
        form:hover
        {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1">
        -- Content --
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: i don't think that rewriting the whole thing is a good solution.